# Postfix delivers to unix user rather than virtual

Tags: postfix

I have setup postfix to use virtual users for inbound emails, with the configuration read from mysql.

However, when I try to deliver a mail locally, using something like `sendmail root@localhost < testmail`, the queries are being executed, but the mail is not delivered to the virtual user directory.
The directory `/var/mail/root` is created instead.

Mysql config seems correct, as the following queries are executed:

```
SELECT destination FROM aliases WHERE mail='root@localhost' and enabled = 1

+----------------+
| destination    |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+

SELECT destination FROM aliases WHERE mail='localhost' and enabled = 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

SELECT domain FROM domains WHERE domain='localhost' and enabled = 1;

+-----------+
| domain    |
+-----------+
| localhost |
+-----------+
```

But they seem to be ignored.
When trying to login through courier IMAP, this results in the following:

```
1 login root@localhost <password>
* BYE [ALERT] Fatal error: No such file or directory: No such file or directory
```

because the folder that postfix created is not the one set in the DB for the user.

### Config

(largely inspired from [a guide](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix)):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +

# working relayhost config here

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: What is the output (when run as root) of postconf ?

Comment: @davidgo it's 900+ lines so can't paste it, but from a quick look it looks right. Any particularly interesting part?

Comment: I don't know what might be interesting, but it strikes me as rather difficult to try and troubleshoot a Postfix configuration without actually seeing the postfix configuration.  Try providing a "postconf -n" which should hopefully be a lot smaller and leave out all the default config stuff.  Of particular interest would be the virtual_* stuff and associated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determinate if postfix is actually delivering to a virtual mailbox, you can check the `relay` value in `/var/log/mail.log`.
Try:

```
tail -100 /var/log/mail.log | grep relay=
```

You are most likely seeing `relay=local`, whereas you want `relay=virtual`.

This happens because postfix is delivering to `local_recipient_maps`.
One indication of this issue is that in your log you can see

```
warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

You can fix this issue by either [overwriting mydestination with an empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377813/postfix-status-bounced-unknown-user-myuser):

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
mydestination =
```

or [forcing postfix to use virtual transport even for local mailboxes](http://xexyl.net/linux/administration/solution-warning-do-not-list-domain-example-com-in-both-mydestination-and-virtual_mailbox_domains):

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
local_transport = virtual
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps
```

The first option is better because it solves the root problem, rather than hammering it in a quiet corner.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the IMAP server getting the mails directly instead of from the maildir? Or /var/mail/foo?

I use dovecot, and I've setup a lmtp forward socket on which dovecot listens. 
When new mail arrives, postfix sends it to dovecot socket. The directory etc is all managed by dovecot.

Comment: I would like to make this work without any extra dependencies such as dovecot if possible. Shouldn't postfix be able to handle virtual directories natively?

Comment: Can you post the configuration and table data for virtual mailbox maps? I sniff some problem there. Or may be the priority is getting messed up, root@localhost is a valid user and postfix directly delivers instead of looking up the tables.